# Weber-type integral

Tags: integration, special-functions, error-function

In connection with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480235/inverse-laplace-transform-of-bar-p-d-frack-0-sqrts-r-dsk-0-sqrts/481946#481946), I came across the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u} \: \,e^{-t u^2} \frac{J_0(u) Y_0(r u)-J_0(r u) Y_0(u)}{J_0^2(u)+Y_0^2(u)}$$

where $r \gt 1$.  I know this looks like an inverse Weber transform, but beyond the fact that the integrand has a name, I could not see how this could help.  Some context:

1) It turns out that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u} \:  \frac{J_0(u) Y_0(r u)-J_0(r u) Y_0(u)}{J_0^2(u)+Y_0^2(u)} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

I know this is correct from the boundary conditions of the problem I solved.  Gradsteyn & Rhyzhik agree.  Of course, I did not derive this directly, so I have no hard proof.

2) Asymptotically, the integrand behaves as

$$\frac{\sin{(r-1) u}}{\sqrt{r} u} e^{-t u^2}$$

This is very interesting, and somewhat expected.  While this is a solution in a 2D, radially-symmetric geometry, the solution of [the analogous problem in 1D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350742/find-the-greens-function-and-solution-of-a-heat-equation-on-the-half-line?lq=1) has an integrand of the form $(\sin{(x u)}/u)\, e^{-t u^2}$.

3) The integral produces a function resembling an error function.

Anyway, any analytical evaluation of the integral that results in a faster evaluation of the result than my using numerical integration will get my appreciation.

Comment: You should ask [Ron](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/53268/ron-gordon).

Comment: @GitGud: I engaged that poor bastard for God-knows how many hours.  He's tired and wants to know whether he was just being stupid.

Comment: Does using Feynman's trick of differentiating w.r.t $t$ under the integral sign help at all?

Comment: @BennettGardiner: no idea.  Please, try it.

Comment: Hey @RonGordon, is there an online copy of Gradsteyn & Rhyzhik to look at? Mathematica seems useless here.

Comment: @BennettGardiner: you can look at portions of it online as far as I know.  The case I explained in 1) is there.

Comment: page number? I found a copy.

Comment: @BennettGardiner Page 673. Formula 6.542. G&R 7$^{th}$ ed. I guess it could be download from [Scrib](http://www.scribd.com/doc/56145998/Table-of-Integrals-Series-and-Products-7Ed-2007-Gradshteyn-I-Ryzhik-I) after login with Scrib or Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for your comment elsewhere. The page itself makes me wonder whether I still have anything to do on the site.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer, but rather a derivation of one of your results that you possibly don’t have a proof for (at least not in the forum anyway).  Firstly consider the Hankel functions of the first and second kind; $H_{v}^{1}\left( z \right)={{J}_{v}}\left( z \right)+i{{Y}_{v}}\left( z \right)$ and $H_{v}^{2}\left( z \right)={{J}_{v}}\left( z \right)-i{{Y}_{v}}\left( z \right)$.
Note that $H_{v}^{1}\left( z \right)$ has zeros in the lower half plane, but not in the upper half plane or on the real axis (the zeros are distributed asymptotically to $-i\log \left( 2 \right)/2n$)

[image: type 1]

Note

$$\frac{H_{v}^{1}\left( bu \right)}{H_{v}^{1}\left( au \right)}\sim \frac{{{a}^{v}}}{{{b}^{v}}} \>   as \>   \left| u \right|\to 0$$ 
and
$$\frac{H_{v}^{1}\left( bu \right)}{H_{v}^{1}\left( au \right)}={{e}^{i\left( b-a \right)u}}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\left( 1+O\left( {{\left| u \right|}^{-1}} \right) \right) \>   as \>  \left| u \right|\to \infty $$
Therefore consider a contour consisting of the real line, indented above z=0 with a small semi-circle of radius $\delta $, and a large semi-circle of radius R in the upper half plane.  Therefore
$$\int\limits_{C}^{{}}{\frac{H_{v}^{1}\left( bz \right)}{H_{v}^{1}\left( az \right)z}dz}=\int\limits_{R}^{{}}{{}}+\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{{}}+\int\limits_{\delta }^{{}}{{}}=0$$
and hence
$$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\frac{H_{v}^{1}\left( bu \right)}{H_{v}^{1}\left( au \right)u}du}=\frac{\pi i{{a}^{v}}}{{{b}^{v}}}$$
Here the integral is understood to be a principal value.   Note the following properties
 $${{Y}_{v}}\left( z{{e}^{m\pi i}} \right)={{e}^{-vm\pi i}}{{Y}_{v}}\left( z \right)+2i\sin \left( vm\pi  \right)\cot \left( v\pi  \right){{J}_{v}}\left( z \right)$$ 
$${{J}_{v}}\left( z{{e}^{m\pi i}} \right)={{e}^{-vm\pi i}}{{J}_{v}}\left( z \right)$$ 
From which it is noted
$$H_{v}^{1}\left( -z \right)={{J}_{v}}\left( -z \right)+i{{Y}_{v}}\left( -z \right)=-{{\left( -1 \right)}^{v}}{{J}_{v}}\left( z \right)+{{\left( -1 \right)}^{v}}\left( i{{Y}_{v}}\left( z \right) \right)={{\left( -1 \right)}^{v-1}}\left( {{J}_{v}}\left( z \right)-i{{Y}_{v}}\left( z \right) \right)={{\left( -1 \right)}^{v-1}}H_{v}^{2}\left( z \right)$$
From this we break the integral in two, i.e.
$$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\frac{H_{v}^{1}\left( bu \right)}{H_{v}^{1}\left( au \right)u}du}=-\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{H_{v}^{1}\left( -bu \right)}{H_{v}^{1}\left( -au \right)u}du}+\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{H_{v}^{1}\left( bu \right)}{H_{v}^{1}\left( au \right)u}du}$$
Or using the results above
$$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\frac{H_{v}^{1}\left( bu \right)}{H_{v}^{1}\left( au \right)u}du}=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{H_{v}^{1}\left( bu \right)H_{v}^{2}\left( au \right)-H_{v}^{2}\left( bu \right)H_{v}^{1}\left( au \right)}{H_{v}^{1}\left( au \right)H_{v}^{2}\left( au \right)u}du}$$
Simplifying this one obtains
$$\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\frac{H_{v}^{1}\left( bu \right)}{H_{v}^{1}\left( au \right)u}du}=2i\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{J}_{v}}\left( au \right){{Y}_{v}}\left( bu \right)-{{J}_{v}}\left( bu \right){{Y}_{v}}\left( au \right)}{\left( J_{v}^{2}\left( au \right)+Y_{v}^{2}\left( au \right) \right)u}du}$$
Finally
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{J}_{v}}\left( au \right){{Y}_{v}}\left( bu \right)-{{J}_{v}}\left( bu \right){{Y}_{v}}\left( au \right)}{\left( J_{v}^{2}\left( au \right)+Y_{v}^{2}\left( au \right) \right)u}du}=\frac{\pi {{a}^{v}}}{2{{b}^{v}}}$$

This result is listed in Bateman.  As for your integral, I have several results, but nothing I am happy with as yet.

Comment: Nice work.  Keep on pushing!

Answer (score 1):

We want to re-express
$$F(k)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x}e^{-kx^2}\frac{J_0(rx)Y_0(x)-J_0(x)Y_0(rx)}{J_0^2(x)+Y_0^2(x)}.$$
Start with
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{b+x^2}\frac{J_0(rx)Y_0(x)-J_0(x)Y_0(rx)}{J_0^2(x)+Y_0^2(x)}dx=-\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{K_0(r\sqrt{b})}{K_0(\sqrt{b})}$$
which can be written as
$$
\int_0^{\infty}dt e^{-bt}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-tx^2}x\frac{J_0(rx)Y_0(x)-J_0(x)Y_0(rx)}{J_0^2(x)+Y_0^2(x)}dx.
$$
$$=\int_0^{\infty}dt e^{-tb}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(t).$$
Now, take the inverse Laplace transform with respect to $b$ to get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(t)=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{db}{2\pi i}e^{bt}\frac{K_0(r\sqrt{b}}{K_0(\sqrt{b})}$$
or
$$F(k)=-\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{ds}{2\pi is}e^{ks}\frac{K_0(r\sqrt{s})}{K_0(\sqrt{s})}.$$
The analysis of this Inverse Laplace transfer is carried out in Carslaw and Jaeger, e.g.

Comment: Larry: thanks.  Unfortunately, your answer is what I started with!  (See the link in the first line of the answer.)  But the reference may be useful - do you have access to a link or soft copy?